# How should I use `withr::with_options()` properly to replace `options() in R?

Tags: r

I tried to replace `options()` with `withr::with_options()` after having run `lint_dir(linted_dir, linters = undesirable_function_linter())`. However, I do not know how to use it properly as it returns an error after having changed it.

```
Error in trace_flow({ : object 'trace.env' not found
```

Former state:

```
  op <- options(trace.env = new.env())
  on.exit(options(op)) # restore options on exit
```

New state:

```
 op <- withr::with_options(trace.env, new.env())
 on.exit(withr::with_options(op)) # restore options on exit
```

See https://github.com/asam-group/rrclust/blob/b3700b6186bae186fc636a106d0cbd9aa7b51f69/R/flow.R#L9 and https://github.com/asam-group/rrclust/blob/b3700b6186bae186fc636a106d0cbd9aa7b51f69/R/flow.R#L10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what `with_options()` does.  It takes two arguments:  the first is a list of options to set, and the second is an expression to evaluate.  It will save the old options, set them to the list you give, evaluate the expression and save the result, restore the old options, and then return the result to you.

You didn't show us what followed your original code, so let's assume it was something like

```
op <- options(trace.env = new.env())
on.exit(options(op)) # restore options on exit
do.something()
result <- do.something.else()
```

The `with_options` equivalent would be

```
result <- withr::with_options( list(trace.env = new.env()),
  {
    do.something()
    do.something.else()
  })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. You can see the use case in which I applied this function in https://github.com/asam-group/rrclust/commit/fc3c737f33e1104707d81ef38a80cf3d77b347eb.